# Ansible: How to Include all hosts but run roles on particular hosts?

Tags: ansible, roles, hosts, ansible-inventory, ansible-facts

I'm trying to include all hosts as I want to use one host facts in other host configuration.

But I have

- tasks common for all
- tasks common for two groups
- tasks for individual group.

When I tried the below way, all tasks are running on all hosts. How can I make sure to apply a role on the specific group ?

```
- hosts: Local:Global:Stream

  tasks:
  - include_role:
      name: global
    when: host in groups['Global']

  - include_role:
      name: local
    when: host in groups['Local']

  - include_role:
      name: stream
    when: host in groups['Stream']
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `inventory_hostname`. I also prefer the dot syntax, though that ought not to matter if you got the name right.

```
when: inventory_hostname in groups.admin
```